# React Navigation onPress in own function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native, react-native-navigation

I've implemented the React Navigation example as in the tutorial https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/ and it works fine.

```
<Button
  onPress={() => navigate('Chat')}
  title="Chat with Lucy"
/>
```

Instead of calling navigate direct in onPress, I want to call it in a separate function btnToChat. I've tried to call it with this.props.navigation.navigate, but it doesn't work. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you!

```
btnToChat(){
  console.log("test");
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Chat');    
}
render() {
  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
return (
  <View>
    <Button
      onPress={this._btnToChat}
    />
  </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The following error appears: undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.navigation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is proper, you just need to bind the `_btnToChat` method to access (correct context) `this` keyword inside that.

Like this:

```
btnToChat = () => {                      //here use arrow  function
    console.log("test");
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Chat');    
}

render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
        <View>
            <Button
                onPress={this._btnToChat}
            />  
        </View>
    );
}
```

Or define the binding of `_btnToChat` method inside `constructor`:

```
constructor(){
   super();
   this._btnToChat = this._btnToChat.bind(this);
}

btnToChat (){           
    console.log("test");
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Chat');    
}

render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
        <View>
            <Button
                onPress={this._btnToChat}
            />  
        </View>
    );
}
```